# Can I apply for a Tier 2 (General) visa if my passport will expire in less than 6 months?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

The [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/documents-you-must-provide) website states that you need a valid travel document to apply for the visa but it doesn't state any minimum validity. Do I need to have more than 6 months in my passport before I apply?

Comment: While you're awaiting a response, take a look at this [great explanation on SE Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66212/uk-tier-2-visa-passport-validity-requirements-on-a-reentry)

Answer (score 1):

I've asked my lawyers and apparently yes I can.

Comment: Since you've answered your own question, can you improve it with the addition official citations/references?

Comment: Your lawyers are correct.